# Pylint: warn of redundant `pylint: disable` comments?

Tags: python, pylint

I created a class:

```py
class Blahaj:
    def swim(self):
        ...

    # todo: consider other modes of transport
```

Pylint warned there were too few public methods, which I acknowledged by adding a  `# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods` comment.

Now I've added more methods, is there a way to get Pylint to warn me that the earlier comment is now redundant?

```py
class Blahaj:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ now redundant
    def swim(self):
        ...

    def jump(self):
        ...

    def fly(self):
        ...

    def ski(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [the `useless-suppression` message](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/information/useless-suppression.html)

Comment: That's perfect, I don't know why I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've manually disabled it, it won't notify you about it anymore for that class. So to answer this, no. There is only your keen eye for re-evaluating disabled checks upon code change.

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out there is a setting: `useless-suppression`. Just in case you/your colleagues need it!